# unpacking a tuple within a UDF taking a tuple as argument

Tags: python, python-3.7, iterable-unpacking

I'm trying to create a function that takes a dictionary whose values are tuples, and a separate tuple as arguments, after which I am trying to compare between their index values as demonstrated below. If they match the key should be entered into a new dictionary.

I've been trying to use tuple unpacking and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong (new to Python):

```py
some_dict = {"a" : (1,2,3), "b" : (1,4,5), "c" : (2,2,3)}
some_tuple = (1,2,5)

def function (some_dict, *some_tuple):
    another_dict = {"match" : [], "no_match" : []}
    some_tuple = list(some_tuple)
    for item in some_dict.values():
        if some_dict[item][0] == some_tuple[0]:
            another_dict["match"].append(item)
        else:
            another_dict["no_match"].append(item)
    return another_dict
```

Comment: are you calling your function like this: `function(some_dict, some_tuple)`? or like this? `function(some_dict, *some_tuple)`?

Comment: actually it would have to be (some_dict, some_tuple). I did try that:  
def function (some_dict, *some_tuple):  
    another_dict = {"match" : [], "no_match" : []}   
    *some_tuple = list(some_tuple)   

 but recieved "SyntaxError: starred assignment target must be in a list or tuple"

Comment: Does your code not do what you want?  Can you show us what you expect the output to be and what you're actually getting?

Answer (score 0):

You first need to put `*` in front of `some_tuple` when you call the function.
OR you can also remove `*` in front of `some_tuple` in the function definition as well.

Also, when you iterating through `some_dict`, I think you don't want to use `values` method. Because I believe you want to iterate through the keys of the dict.

Try the following:

```py
some_dict = {"a": (1, 2, 3), "b": (1, 4, 5), "c": (2, 2, 3)}
some_tuple = (1, 2, 5)


def function(some_dict, *some_tuple):
    another_dict = {"match": [], "no_match": []}
    some_tuple = list(some_tuple)
    for item in some_dict:
        if some_dict[item][0] == some_tuple[0]:
            another_dict["match"].append(item)
        else:
            another_dict["no_match"].append(item)
    return another_dict


print(function(some_dict, *some_tuple))
```

```
{'match': ['a', 'b'], 'no_match': ['c']}
```